# Android custom theme won't apply

Tags: android-studio, android-actionbar, android-theme

For my application I want to make a custom theme with just a different color for my actionbar. So I found a theme generator on the Internet:'Android Action Bar Style Generator'. I picked some color and downloaded the theme, put my downloaded stuff in the res-folder and changed the 'style' to my new theme. For some reason my theme never applies to my application. It always uses the baseTheme which is also specified in the downloaded theme. This is my manifest file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.jobslot.indupac" >

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/bpi_logo_transparant_background"
            android:label="Indupac"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity
                android:name=".LoginActivity"
                android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name=".SettingsActivity">
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name=".GraphActivity">
            </activity>
        </application>
    </manifest>
```

This is my style:

```
    <resources>
        <color name="basic_text">#000000</color>
        <color name="basic_text_buttons">#FFFFFF</color>
        <color name="blue_bpi">#003676</color>
        <color name="light_green_bpi">#D6FFDA</color>
        <style
            name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Indupac">
        </style>
    </resources>
```

Comment: You should provide more details. Anyway try to read something about the AppCompat v21 and the new Toolbar. You don't need the ActionBar Style Generator. It is deprecated now.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my problem. When I applied the default theme "@style.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" and added "colorPrimary" as an item, then it worked like a charm. Keep in mind not to put "android:" in front of "colorPrimary", because that requires API 21. Here is what i got:

```
    <resources>
        <color name="basic_text">#000000</color>
        <color name="basic_text_buttons">#FFFFFF</color>
        <color name="blue_bpi">#003676</color>
        <color name="light_green_bpi">#D6FFDA</color>
        <style
            name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
            <item name="colorPrimary">@color/blue_bpi</item>
            <item name="colorAccent">@color/blue_bpi</item>
        </style>
    </resources>
```

Comment: It is the appCompat v21+. I suggest use colors.xml for colors, and styles.xml for styles and themes.